# Is there a way to insert and edit a geographic map chart in an Excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I want data that I pull to insert a state map at the county level but also add an appropriate title and change the diverging intervals in the Format Data Series toolbar inside the chart.

I recorded the process and the code will insert the state map but won't make the edits that I want.

My data headers are: State County Ratio.

Here's the code I recorded:

```vb
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-90
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(494, xlRegionMap).Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8").Activate

ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "NCAT LR by County"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorGradientStyle = _
    xlSeriesColorGradientStyleDiverging
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMinGradientStop. _
    StopPositionType = xlGradientStopPositionTypeNumber
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopValue = _
    "-0.102"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMidGradientStop. _
    StopPositionType = xlGradientStopPositionTypeNumber
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopValue = _
    "0.81"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMaxGradientStop. _
    StopPositionType = xlGradientStopPositionTypeNumber
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopValue = _
    "1.721"
With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopColor.RGB = 5287936
    .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopColor.Transparency = 0
End With
With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopColor.ObjectThemeColor = 2
    .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopColor.Transparency = 0
End With
With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.RGB = 255
    .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.Transparency = 0
End With
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopValue = "0"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopValue = _
    "0.50"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopValue = "1"
Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
```

It appears the first error occurs where it says "ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8").Activate" and the error message is:

> "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you closer:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cht As Chart, co, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
    
    Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(494, xlRegionMap)
    co.Visible = True

    Set cht = co.Chart 'this is the chart you just created
    
    With cht
        .ChartTitle.Caption = "NCAT LR by County"
        
        With .FullSeriesCollection(1)
            .SeriesColorGradientStyle = xlSeriesColorGradientStyleDiverging
            .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopPositionType = xlGradientStopPositionTypeNumber
            .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopValue = "-0.102"
            .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopPositionType = xlGradientStopPositionTypeNumber
            .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopValue = "0.81"
            .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopPositionType = xlGradientStopPositionTypeNumber
            .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopValue = "1.721"
    
            .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopColor.RGB = 5287936
            .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopColor.Transparency = 0
            .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopColor.ObjectThemeColor = 2
            .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopColor.RGB = 255
            
            .SeriesColorMinGradientStop.StopValue = "0"
            .SeriesColorMidGradientStop.StopValue = "0.50"
            .SeriesColorMaxGradientStop.StopValue = "1"
        End With
    End With
    
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! One more question: would there be any syntax for also sizing the map chart automatically as well?

Comment: You can position and size using the `co.Top/Left/Height/Width` properties

Comment: Perfect got it! Thank you very much for your help.